# How to show clock in Windows 10 when app is full screen?

Tags: windows-10

When a Windows app is full screen in Windows 10, the Task Bar is no longer visible. In Windows 8, users could simply hit `WinKey+c` and the system would overlay a clock (and date and battery level and wifi status). How does a user show the clock in Windows 10 when an app is Full Screen?

As an aside, I would like to accomplish this without changing the context of the user. That is to say, hitting `WinKey` by itself (which would result in the taskbar/tray clock being visible) is a possible solution but also takes away the focus of the current app. It's a solution, but not a great one.

Comment: [I enabled tablet mode on my Windows 10 machine, launched a Universal Windows Application, I saw my taskbar, start menu,  and clock at all times.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iqEXQ.png)

Comment: Try running the app full screen. Perhaps you are confusing FullScreen with Maximized. You can run a Windows 8 app (like 80% in the store) to see the same effect. The TaskBar does not show up. Then how do I show the clock?

Comment: The application is full screen in that screenshot.